# 'Add theme settings for configuration' in shopify - Error message 'unexpected token' keeps coming up?

Tags: configuration, themes, schema, shopify, unexpected-token

I'm following instructions on shopify developers to create a 'How did you hear about us form field' for my website. FYI I am using safari on a Mac. Everything was working fine until I got to the step of 'Add theme settings for configuration.' In the Config. directory of settings_schema-json, the current code (below) already exists:

```
[
  {
    "name": "theme_info",
    "theme_name": "Themekit template theme",
    "theme_version": "1.0.0",
    "theme_author": "Shopify",
    "theme_documentation_url": "https:\/\/github.com\/Shopify\/themekit",
    "theme_support_url": "https:\/\/github.com\/Shopify\/themekit\/issues"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to add to that code with the code pasted below from shopify developers, which I'm told to paste on a new line below the closing curly bracket (above). But each time I do that and hit save, two error messages come up (see attached screenshot at bottom of post). The messages read 'An error prevented settings_schema.json from being saved' and  'Invalid JSON: unexpected token.' Does anybody have any idea what's going wrong here? I would be very grateful as I'm brand new to coding and this is the first time I've tried to make any changes to my website!

Thanks, Cosmo.

```
{
"name": "Hear About Us",
"settings": [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "hau_form_options",
        "label": "Form options",
        "default": "Facebook, Twitter, Google, Instagram, Youtube",
        "info": "Separate each option with a comma"
    },
    {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Form validation"
    },
    {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "hau_form_validation",
        "label": "Enable form validation",
        "default": true
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "hau_error_message",
        "label": "Error message",
        "info": "The error message that is displayed when no selection is made",
        "default": "Please select an option below"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "hau_error_message_other",
        "label": "Other field error message",
        "info": "The error message that is displayed when there is no input in the 'Other' field",
        "default": "Please fill the text field below"
    },
    {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Error styling"
    },
    {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "hau_error_color",
        "label": "Color",
        "default": "#ff0000"
    }
]
},
```

[screenshot error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRMmH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a comma `,`, correct it and works fine
[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: Hi Onkar I just tried adding in the comma but the error message is still coming up... ?

Comment: shared JSON is valid might be an issue in somewhere bellow into the code, you need to share the full code using gist or something similar to check and debug https://prnt.sc/zzht99

Comment: Hi Onkar I've just made a gist through GitHub and here is the URL to the code. Let me know if you can open it: https://gist.github.com/cosmofry/b402a8e1bf3237e913a6134a21520c07

Comment: In revisions it says 'no newline at end of file' but even when I take this line out the error message still pops up when I hit save

Comment: Edit the answer, you can check there are 2 mistakes in JSON code one on top you not add the `,` before the new node and at the end, you need to remove the last comma `,`. you can easily check the validity of the JSON data using an online tool link [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: You are a genius, it works now. Thank you Onkar

Comment: Glad to know it help you, please accept it as the answer to this question also.